# Effective way. of comparing list elements in Java

Tags: java, string, list, compare, contains

Is there any **effective way **of comparing elements in Java and print out the position of the element which occurs once.
For example: if I have a list: ["Hi", "Hi", "No"], I want to print out 2 because "No" is in position 2. I have solved this using the following algorithm and it works, **BUT** the problem is that if I have a large list it takes too much time to compare the entire list to print out the first position of the unique word.

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
    int oc = Collections.frequency(strings, strings.get(i));
    if (oc == 1)
        System.out.print(i);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Do you only want the first non duplicate value index?

Comment: Yes, I should put a break but it still very slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of counting each element's occurrence no and filter out the first element though not sure how large your list is.

Using Stream:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Hi", "Hi", "No");
//iterating thorugh the list and storing each element and their no of occurance in Map
Map<String, Long> counts = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
String value = counts.entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1) //filtering out all the elements which have more than 1 occurance
                    .map(Map.Entry::getKey) // creating a stream of element from map as all of these have only single occurance
                    .findFirst() //finding the first element from the element stream
                    .get();
System.out.println(list.indexOf(value));
```

**EDIT:**
A simplified version can be

```
Map<String, Long> counts2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Long>();
for(String val : list){
    long count = counts2.getOrDefault(val, 0L);
    counts2.put(val, ++count);
}
for(String key: counts2.keySet()){
    if(counts2.get(key)==1){
        System.out.println(list.indexOf(key));
        break;
    }
}
```

The basic idea is to count each element's occurrence and store them in a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html?is-external=true).Once you have count of all elements occurrences. then you can simply check for the first element which one has 1 as count.

Comment: That works and is quite concise, but perhaps a bit advanced for the OP's question. I think you should explain more what your code does, what a `LinkedHashMap` is etc

Comment: Seems to work but I dont understand it ;(

Comment: @Dici thanks for the suggestion I have put some comments in stream code.

Comment: @ZedORYasuo I added a simplified version.

Comment: It seems to work fine!  Thank you! But I get some weird error that the memory exceeded? Do you know why? @SayanBhattacharya

Comment: In general, that will mean that your program is taking more memory than what has been allocated to JVM. But I will suggest you search the error in internet/ Stackoverflow you will be able to find many answers then. @ZedORYasuo

Answer (score 1):

If there's only one word that's present only once, you can probably use a `HashMap` or `HashSet` + `Deque` (set for values, `Deque` for indices) to do this in linear time. A sort can give you the same in `n log(n)`, so slower than linear but a lot faster than your solution. By sorting, it's easy to find in linear time (after the sort) which element is present only once because all duplicates will be next to each other in the array.

For example for a linear solution in pseudo-code (pseudo-Kotlin!):

```
counters = HashMap()
for (i, word in words.withIndex()) {
   counters.merge(word, Counter(i, 1), (oldVal, newVal) -> Counter(oldVald.firstIndex, oldVald.count + newVal.count)); 
   
}

for (counter in counters.entrySet()) {
    if (counter.count == 1) return counter.firstIndex;
}

class Counter(firstIndex, count)
```

Comment: I see. Do you have any example of how?

Comment: I added pseudo-code, but I believe you can code the rest yourself, it will teach you more ;)

Comment: @OP - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html

Comment: Not sure what you mean kleopatra. I'm explicitly sharing pseudo-code

Comment: didn't mean you @Dici - should have been more clear, though, sorry ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use HashMap.For example you can put word as key and index as value.Once you find the same word you can delete the key and last the map contain the result.

Comment: Im not really sure how its done. Do you have an example with code?

Comment: HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>;
for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++){
    if(map.get(list.get(i))!=null){
        map.delete(list.get(i));
    }else{
      map.put(list.get(i),i);
    }
}
Syetem.println.out(map.keySet());

Comment: Hey @yufangwu, I invite you to not share a full code snippet here, I think the OP can come up with the full code if you explain the idea well enough. Your idea definitely works.

Answer (score 1):

## Map<String,Boolean> + loops

Instead of using `Map<String,Integer>` as suggested in other answers.

You can maintain a `HashMap` (if you need to maintain the order, use `LinkedHashMap` instead) of type `Map<String,Boolean>` where a *value* would denote whether an element is unique or not.

The simplest way to generate the map is method `put()` in conjunction with `containsKey()` check.

But there are also more concise options like [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#replace(K,V)) + [`putIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent(K,V)). `putIfAbsent()` would create a new entry only if key is not present in the map, therefore we can associate such string with a value of `true` (considered to be unique). On the other hand `replace()` would update only existing entry (otherwise map would not be effected), and if entry exist, the key is proved to be a duplicate, and it has to be associated with a value of `false` (non-unique).

And since Java 8 we also have method [`merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)), which expects tree arguments: a *key*, a *value*, and a *function* which is used when the given *key* already exists to resolve the *old value* and the *new one*.

The last step is to generate list of unique strings by iterating over the *entry set* of the newly created map. We need every *key* having a *value* of `true` (is unique) associated with it.

```
List<String> strings = // initializing the list
        
Map<String, Boolean> isUnique = new HashMap<>(); // or LinkedHashMap if you need preserve initial order of strings
        
for (String next: strings) {
    isUnique.replace(next, false);
    isUnique.putIfAbsent(next, true);
//      isUnique.merge(next, true, (oldV, newV) -> false); // does the same as the commented out lines above
    }
        
List<String> unique = new ArrayList<>();
        
for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry: isUnique.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue()) unique.add(entry.getKey());
}
```

## Stream-based solution

With streams, it can be done using collector `toMap()`. The overall logic remains the same.

```
List<String> unique = strings.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap( // creating intermediate map Map<String, Boolean>
        Function.identity(),   // key
        key -> true,           // value
        (oldV, newV) -> false, // resolving duplicates
        LinkedHashMap::new     // Map implementation, if order is not important - discard this argument
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .filter(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .toList(); // for Java 16+ or collect(Collectors.toList()) for earlier versions
```